# JS: How to cancel a timeOut even from Firing if some other event has been fired

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a Promise chain in my UI which sends data to my server.

On success/Fail the server updates the datamodel which generates and event. This event tells my UI, that the process was successful.

However, in case there was some issue at my server end, I need a timeout at the UI to say the config failed.

The problem is even if there was an event already, the timeout using setTimeout still fires. setTimeout is within promise chain, while event listener is outside the promise chain.

How do I make sure that when the event has been already received the timeout is not fired? Or any alternative/better way of solving this problem. I am very very new to JS and Web Programming. So, forgive my ignorance.

```
function initialize() {
    event.onValue(function(eventData) {
        //display success fail.
        //unblock UI for new config.
        //cancel the timeout from firing in sendConfigData?
    })

    $(#sendConfigData).asEventStream("click").onValue(function() {
        sendConfigData();
    }
}

function sendConfigData() {
    Promise.try(function() {
        disableNewConfigFromUser();
        return verifyUserData();
    })
    .then (function (userData) {
        return sendUserDataToServer();
    }
    .then (function () {
        setTimeout(function(){
            //conifg Faile. Enable new conifg data from user.
        }, timeOut);
    })
    .catch(function(){
        log("Request Rejected by Server");
    });
}
```

Comment: If I understand what you try to achieve, you could simply use a boolean that would be defined on a higher scope that both your event listener and your promise could reach. Update it in the listener and check it in the promise to fire the setTimeout or not.